# HTML partial rendered in JS view is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `Session`, which `has_many` `ExperimentSessions`. In `sessions/show.js.erb` I render a `Session`'s `ExperimentSessions` using a partial:

```
#/sessions/show.js.erb
<% out = '' %>
<% fields_for @session do |sess_f| %>
  <%  sess_f.fields_for :experiment_sessions, child_index: "", index:nil  do |f| %>
    <% out += j "<li class='list-group-item'>"%>
    <% out += j render partial: 'experiment_sessions/exp_sess', locals: {f:f}  %>
    <% out += j "</li>"%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This works well. However, I'd like to put this into its own partial view to reuse it. I have this:

```
#/sessions/_exp_sessions_li.html.erb
<% fields_for session do |sess_f| %>
  <%  sess_f.fields_for :experiment_sessions, child_index: "", index:nil  do |f| %>
    <%= "<li class='list-group-item'>"%>
    <%= render partial: 'experiment_sessions/exp_sess', locals: {f:f}  %>
    <%= "</li>"%>
  <% end%>
<% end %>
```

and include it in `show.js.erb`:

```
#/sessions/show.js.erb
<% out = j(render(partial: 'exp_sessions_li', locals: {session: @session}  )) %>
```

From the logs, there are no errors, and the partials get rendered. However, `out` is the empty string.
Why does `_exp_sessions_li.html.erb` produce empty output?

---

**Edit: clarify logs**

`logger.ap @session` output in `show.js.erb`:

```
#<Session:0x007fc4859748d8> {
            :id => 732187210,
   :recorded_on => Fri, 20 Mar 2015 00:00:00 EDT -04:00,
         :notes => "session_j_b_ 15",
    :created_at => Fri, 20 Mar 2015 00:00:00 EDT -04:00,
    :updated_at => Fri, 20 Mar 2015 00:00:00 EDT -04:00
}
```

`logger.ap @session.experiment_sessions` shows these objects as well. `session` is also visible as expected in `/sessions/_exp_sessions_li.html.erb`.

Log indicates the partials get rendered:

```
Rendered experiment_sessions/_exp_sess.html.erb (0.7ms)
Rendered experiment_sessions/_exp_sess.html.erb (0.6ms)
Rendered sessions/_exp_sessions_li.html.erb (4.9ms)
```

---

**Edit: drill down on partial**

Replacing the contents of `_exp_sessions_li.html.erb` with a string will render that string. Furthermore, if I edit this file to be

```
aa
<% fields_for session do |sess_f| %>
  bb
  <% sess_f.fields_for :experiment_sessions, child_index: "", index:nil  do |f| %>
    cc
    <%= "<li class='list-group-item'>"%>
    <%= render partial: 'experiment_sessions/exp_sess', locals: {f:f}  %>
[...]
```

will only show '`aa`' in `out`. So `fields_for` seems to eat the output. Note that the logs still say `exp_sess` gets rendered.

Now, if I write `<%= fields_for session do |sess_f| %>`, output also contains '`bb`'. And adding `<%= sess_f.fields_for ...` also the rest. The raw HTML parts (`<li ..`) are escaped, however.

Comment: Can you please log `@session` in `/sessions/show.js.erb` and let me know if it has anything in it? Thanks

Comment: Can you please do this? Remove everything from the `_exp_sessions_li.html.erb` partial and just pass a simple string and see if that string will log in the `out` variable. Thanks

Comment: Found my mistake, thanks for putting me in right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my mistake was to not return the output of the `fields_for` blocks.

The reason my original code works is that I add the output of every line to my output variable (including output of `j` calls, which were the only reason the `<li ...` lines were sent through ruby in the first place).

Simply writing `<%= fields_for`… solves my issue.